Variable initialization results in an IndexOutOfRangeException
I'm making an open source Unity game and programming like normal when I suddenly came across an IndexOutOfRangeException when clicking the button.

IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
at SaveFileScript.OnMouseUp () [0x00074] in C:\Users***\PC Simulator Save Editor 2\Assets\Scripts\SaveFileScript.cs:14
at UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents+HitInfo.SendMessage (System.String name) [0x0000a] in \home\bokken\build\output\unity\unity\Modules\InputLegacy\MouseEvents.cs:19
at UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents.SendEvents (System.Int32 i, UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents+HitInfo hit) [0x000a6] in \home\bokken\build\output\unity\unity\Modules\InputLegacy\MouseEvents.cs:240
at UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents.DoSendMouseEvents (System.Int32 skipRTCameras) [0x0038d] in \home\bokken\build\output\unity\unity\Modules\InputLegacy\MouseEvents.cs:208
UnityEngine.HitInfo:SendMessage(String) (at \home\bokken\build\output\unity\unity\Modules\InputLegacy\MouseEvents.cs:19)
UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:SendEvents(Int32, HitInfo) (at \home\bokken\build\output\unity\unity\Modules\InputLegacy\MouseEvents.cs:240)
Unity UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMou

Code
   string output = "";
   foreach (char str in OpenFileScript.Contents) {
       output += (char) (str ^ 0x81);
   }
   string[] readyOut = output.Split('\n'); //<<<<<<<<<<< IndexOutOfRangeException
   readyOut[1] = readyOut[1].Remove(readyOut[1].Length);
   File.WriteAllLines( filePath, readyOut );
   NativeFilePicker.ExportFile(filePath);   

When printing output, its indeed valid.
It only occurs when inside a variable initialization.
When I relocate it to the second argument of File.WriteAllLines, everything works fine.
string[] readyOut = output.Split('\n'); // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>↴
readyOut[1] = readyOut[1].Remove(readyOut[1].Length);   //↓ ✅
File.WriteAllLines( filePath, output.Split('\n') );// <<<<↲

I expected:

It to successfully initialize without erroring.

What actually happened

In the middle of the code, initializing the variable throws an error.

I tried:

Renaming the variable

Changing the type to var



Did you inspect if readyOut has 2 or more elements? Since you're trying to access second item.

have you considered that output may not have a \n ?

I strongly suspect that the stack trace has an off-by-one error, and that it's actually readyOut[1] = readyOut[1].Remove(readyOut[1].Length); that is failing. I suggest you add some more logging to validate that.

It was actually because of confusion that resulted in this error. I meant to not split the lines since it should be 1 lines only. Let me make it remove the last character of the string itself, not the string array.

Looks like you've made an incorrect assumption that when
OpenFileScript.Contents

is called, there are some contents, when in fact there are none.
That means the body of your foreach does not execute, which in turn means output is empty (""). When your output is empty, accessing the second element of readyElement is going to be non-existent because readyOut will be an array of size 1 containing just the empty string.
Proving the point: moving the call inline (clever in-code diagram) and I assume commenting out the [1] access leaves you with a working solution for the empty content case (which runs just fine because you can write nothing with File.WriteAllLines() all day long).
To Jon Skeet's comment, that is probably true. I'm not a Unity programmer, but given games need to be optimized, there's probably some reflection emit and code-gen involved, which can be prone to resetting line numbers in the debug metadata.
A simple check will help
string[] readyOut = output.Split('\n'); //<<<<<<<<<<< no, not IndexOutOfRangeException
if (readyOut.Length > 1)
    readyOut[1] = readyOut[1].Remove(readyOut[1].Length); //<<< no exception either


indices are 0-bases .. so if (readyOut.Length != 0) can still throw an exception for accessing index 1 (the second item) you would need to check for if(readOut.Length > 1) instead

Oops. Yeah, good catch. Fixed.
